# How do I save object order in Parse.com / backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, parse-platform

I have a list of folders belonging to a user, and I want them to be able to reorder them by dragging and dropping.  I can get the drag-drop to work okay, but I can't figure out how to save the results.  I'm using Parse, and I think that means I have to retrieve each object, change the order attribute, and then resave it... but that doesn't seem to be working, as they all come out with the same order.

After sorting and then doing .sortable('toArray'), I have an array of folder ids, prepended with the word 'folder', so it looks something like ["folder_ab9gu3nd", "folder_kwkgiutyqo", "folder_s856skt8w"].

So, I want to save folder ab9gu3nd with order 0, kwkgiutyqo with order 1, and s856skt8w with order 2.

Here's my code ('result' is the array with the folder ids):

```
        for(var ii=0; ii<result.length; ii++) {
                            // Get actual id
            var folderId = result[ii].replace('folder_', '');
            var folderOrder = ii;
            var folder = Parse.Object.extend("Folder");
            var query = new Parse.Query(folder);
            query.get(folderId, {
                success: function(folder) {
                    // The object was retrieved successfully.
                    folder.set('order', folderOrder);
                    folder.save();
                }
            });
        }
```

When I run this, the folders all end up with order '2', as if the final value of ii was used for all of them.  How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being fooled by two things:

1. Your `var`s inside the loop are hoisted to the surrounding function, they're not local to the loop.
2. Your `success` handlers are triggered asynchronously and they're closures over **exactly the same `folderOrder`**.

For the first one, your loop actually looks like this as far as JavaScript is concerned:

```
function whateverItIsCalled() {
    var folderId, folderOrder, folder, query, ii;
    //...
    for(ii = 0; ii < result.length; ii++) {
        //...
        folderOrder = ii;
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

so there is only one `folderOrder` for the entire function and your loop simply assigns `ii` to it on each iteration.

The second problem is the usual "AJAX in a loop" problem: you're constructing a series of anonymous functions which are closures over the same `folderOrder` variable. The result of that is that the all three of your `success` handlers end up referencing the same `folderOrder` value and, by the time they are triggered, the loop will be finished and `folderOrder` will have its last value from the loop; the last value in your case is two.

To solve your problem, you just need to get separate `folderOrder` values into the various `success` handlers. One way is to use a function to generate your success handlers:

```
function makeSuccess(folderOrder) {
    return function(folder) {
        folder.set('order', folderOrder);
        folder.save();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
query.get(folderId, {
    success: makeSuccess(folderOrder)
});
```

Another common approach is to use a self-executing function to effectively creating a distinct scope for the loop's body:

```
for(var ii = 0; ii < result.length; ii++)
    (function(ii) {
        // Same stuff you currently have...
    })(ii);
```

Which approach you take is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Thank you, that's brilliant.  I've implemented the second approach, for the sake of speed, but I'll take a look at the first one when I have a bit more time.